# Flash error 5001: name of package does not reflect location?

Tags: flash, package

I'm getting an error on Flash that I've never run in to before.

> 5001: The name of package 'Document'
>   does not reflect the location of this
>   file. Please change the package
>   definition's name inside this file, or
>   move the file. C:\Work\2009-2010\Flash\Tests\Document.as

The fla is called TestEvents1... and that's all the info I think is related.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the fla and Document.as in the same folder? If not, you will need to change the package name in order to indicate where Document.as can be found.

this article may help:
http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/698/1/Make-your-own-reusable-classes-using-Flash-and-AS3/Page1.html